# Reordering a list of positional items

Tags: c#

I have a Request object which contains a list of Approvers. An approver has a name and an approval position.

1. Mathew
2. Mark
3. Luke
4. John

Ultimately, a request will move through this chain, starting at Mathew and ended at John.

I need to be able to re-order these allowing adds and deletes as outlined below.

An approver can be -

Added at a certain position - ie. Add Peter at position 3 in which case the new order would be

1. Mathew
2. Mark
3. Peter
4. Luke
5. John

Delete - ie. Delete Mark in which case the new order is

1. Mathew
2. Luke
3. John

Edited - ie you can change John's position to 1 in which case the new order is

1. John
2. Mathew
3. Mark
4. Luke

I have come up with a number of solutions, however none of them is particular elegant.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How large are the lists likely to be? [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) is likely to be the easiest representation of the collection, but it means a copy is required every time you insert into or remove from the middle of the list. "Editing" the list basically means a remove/insert.

Iteration is then straightforward.

An alternative might be [`LinkedList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx) - which makes iteration simple and "insert after", "insert before" and "delete" cheap *if* you hang onto the [`LinkedListNode<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d97b9a15.aspx) associated with each of your approvers. But it doesn't make it easy to say "this reviewer should now be at position 3" - you'd have to iterate through to find position 3 first (or 2, anyway). If it's a case of "move this approver after this one" then it's ideal.

Answer (score 4):

Maintaining a position property is a pain, as you need to make lots of modifications to change something (while keeping everything logical). It also makes it hard to serialize/deserialize efficiently.

Can you not simply infer the position from the position in a `List<T>` or similar? Then you can `Add()` to the end, `Insert()` to the middle and `Remove()` from anywhere. To move something you simply `Remove()` it and `Insert()` it at the position you want?

Like so (formatted for space):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;

// I only added this to use a lazier "collection initializer" below,
// which needs an Add(string) method...
class ApproverCollection : Collection<Approver> {
    public void Add(string name) { Add(new Approver(name)); }
}
class Request {
    public Request() { Approvers = new ApproverCollection(); }
    public ApproverCollection Approvers { get; private set; }
}
class Approver {
    public Approver(string name) { Name = name; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
static class Program {
    static void Main() {
        Request req = new Request {
            Approvers = {"Mathew", "Mark", "Luke", "John"}
        };
        req.ShowState("Initial");
        req.Approvers.Insert(2, new Approver("Peter"));
        req.ShowState("Inserted Peter");
        Approver mark = req.Approvers.Single(x => x.Name == "Mark");
        req.Approvers.Remove(mark);
        req.ShowState("Removed Mark");
        Approver john = req.Approvers.Single(x => x.Name == "John");
        req.Approvers.Remove(john);
        req.Approvers.Insert(0, john);
        req.ShowState("Moved John");
    }
    static void ShowState(this Request request, string caption) {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(caption);
        int pos = 1;
        foreach(Approver a in request.Approvers) {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", pos++, a.Name);
        }
    }
}
```